# How to prevent the media keys from waking the MacBook Pro screen?

Tags: keyboard, display

When I'm putting on music I sometimes turn off the screen with the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd>. However, when I use the media keys the screen wakes up and I have put it to sleep again.
Ideally the media keys would not alter the state of the screen, is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: What you want is AFAIK not possible but my old Macbook can switch off the screen completely if I set brightness to the leftmost position. No key except F2/Brightness Up can't change it.

Comment: True, this works but is not as convenient as just hitting the key combination described. Besides, setting the brightness to 0 does not actually sleep the monitor and may consume more battery than putting the monitor to sleep.

Comment: You can create a script to set brightness to 0 and assign it to shortcut. Creating a rule that pressing same shortcut 2nd time revert brightness back. It's switching off lamps/leds which are most power hungry part of the screen I believe. Never checked if still redraw pixels though.

Comment: @iskra Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into that. However, keep in mind: brightness = 0 is not equal to putting the display to sleep. If you set the brightness to 0, the screen is still active and redraws, only it is very very dim. Simple test: set the brightness to 0, hold a light source very close to the edge of the screen, you will see the very dim display where mouse movements are visible (at least on a mid 2009 MBP).

Comment: Let us know on the progress then. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable the screen from waking on keyboard input, unfortunately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: There is no answer to the question because it's not possible to do what they are asking...I changed the word "computer" to "screen" to match the question, but the underlying response is the same.

Comment: I agree with Mark, I believe it's better if you delete your answer and be getting badge for that.

Comment: If there is a better answer, please post it. What the author is asking to do is not possible, short of unplugging the keyboard from the computer (and at that point he can't use the media keys, which defeats the purpose).

Comment: I've commented under his question with workaround.