# Changing Volume Without Waking Display Screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, sleep-wake

I am using the `Hot Corners` feature to turn my display off on my Macbook Pro (OS X 10.8.4) when I am not using it. Oftentimes, I keep music playing and I want to change the volume while the display is off. Every time I increase or decrease the volume, the screen turns on, and I have to turn the display off again.

Is there a way in ML to change the volume without waking the screen again? I know that it is *supposed* to wake the screen when the user presses something, but is there a way to maintain that functionality for everything *but* the volume buttons? If that's not possible, are there any third party apps that could do this?

Comment: [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98854/how-to-prevent-the-media-keys-from-waking-the-macbook-pro-screen) is not in relation to the exact same keys but as far as I know the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a remote connection to your computer from another computer or phone. Using a Terminal app from your phone, for example, you can remote in and then run a command like:

```
# Where 50 is a number from 0 to 100
osascript -e 'set volume output volume 50'
```

If you did this a lot you could create an alias in your .bashrc (or other shell profile file) for a shorter easier command.

I have a remote mouse app on my phone and it wakes up the screen, so you'd need a true remote control otherwise.